# "Another display not detected" but is detected. How can I fix for 3rd monitor?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've got 2 monitors working through VGA. I'm trying to get the third monitor working through HDMI and having some trouble.

In the Windows 7 Control Panel -> Screen Resolution I've got this:

[image]

In the Device Manager all 3 are showing up:

[image]

The one that isn't working is the one connected by HDMI. I couldn't find any Questions/Answers that involved that "Another display not detected message" in this fashion. Anyone know how I can get the third display to work?

**Additional Image for Comments**

[image]

Comment: @DaveRook as you can see in the second image: Intel HD Graphics 4000 or is that not it?

Comment: `I've got 2 monitors working through serial` - What? How are these monitors connected? VGA? DVI?

Comment: @joeqwerty I edited right before you posted that. VGA. Sorry haven't had enough coffee yet.

Comment: Gotcha. No worries.

Comment: I would just try and select something other then "disconnect this display"

Comment: @Ramhound ... if that was the answer I wouldn't be asking on here. Extend Desktop to this Display isn't working.

Comment: @Ryan it is, but what generation?

Comment: @DaveRook updated with image for you

Comment: Based on the supported configuration that David posted you won't be able to use VGA and have 3 displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up as per the screen shot below, assuming the combination of your chipset and card supports it

[image]

[More details](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-031040.htm)

I also suggest you read http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033714.htm as it's dedicated to 3 displays by Intel... Sadly, there is too much to copy here, and since we're not really sure what reason your 3rd display isn't working I can't even copy just the relevant part so sorry for just a link...

However, try pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F12` to open the Intel graphic options and set it from there... (details in the link aboce)

Comment: Already tried the `Ctrl+Alt+F12` interface it only detects two of the monitors.

Comment: Sadly, this may indicate that maybe the combination you have doesn't work. I've seen a few people with similar issues, I wish companies would stop advertising as 3 monitor etc because it's only 3 monitor with very specific conditions which are not always apparent at first :( Check out the 2 links I've provided, hopefully something there may help

Comment: Well this is a computer my boss built so can't blame the companies. It looks like I might need to get some different wiring. VGA/VGA/n only works with WiDi. Looks like two monitors it is for me.

Comment: Yep sure enough unplugged one of the VGA's and instantly the HDMI worked. That's unfortunate. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 3):

Select the Monitor which is not extended to. 
Number 2 in your screenshot, then in the multiple display drop down select extend to this display.

This worked for me.

Ivan

Answer (score 1):

Under resolution: Right Click on the display that is not being detected and then select Extend desktop to this display under the multiple displays section.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and was able to fix it. Here are the details:

**Scenario in Sequential Order:**
First - after putting my pc to sleep, pushing the power button would turn the pc on but none of the screens would turn on unless I force-shut down my pc by holding the power button down.
Second - When I could get my screens to turn on, only two of my monitors functioned properly. The third monitor would be detected but "Display Settings" wouldn't allow me to extend to the third screen. I could choose the "Extend desktop to this display" but my pc would just freeze and revert the change after about 5 to 10 seconds.
Third - I tried restarting my pc and it would no longer turn on. (Panic mode initiated).

**The Problem (In my unprofessional opinion but based on past experience):**
There were way too many devices plugged into one single circuit.

Explanation - My pc's power supply (PSU) was not receiving enough power to properly power my graphics card. Specifically, I had - 3 monitors, 2 additional laptops (I work from home), 2 chargers, a fan, and whatever other devices located in different rooms but still on the same circuit - plugged in at the same time.

**The Solution:**
I ran an extension cord from an outlet on a different circuit to my pc, and only my pc.

Explanation - This fixed all my issues (excluding daddy and marital issues). I initially tried plugging my pc into the outlet nearby, which was on the same circuit, and that did not work; the pc still would not turn on. To elaborate, and based on my limited experience working with electricity under my neighbor electrician's supervision, each circuit in a home can only handle so much load (the amount of energy each device/appliance takes up added together) and when that threshold is met, things stop working properly. Think of when you turn on a vacuum or other big appliance and the lights flicker. The flickering is your lights screaming "I'm not getting enough power for my intended purpose." This was the scenario with my monitors except my third monitor couldn't scream, it just kept quiet.

Thank you to anyone reading this and I hope this solution and the lightly sprinkled jokes could brighten your day. I know you're probably frustrated or panicking if you're coming across this forum.

**Note:** I also dusted my pc out as best I could, so this could have contributed to the third monitor solution but did not solve the no power issue, so I still think adequate power was the main culprit.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed this issue.

My laptop has one VGA, one HDMI and one mini-port to HDMI.

I connected VGA first which then detected two monitors 1/2 (one being the laptop screen which I keep closed and don't use).  I selected 2 as the main display.  I selected 'Show only on 2' and disconnected 1, the laptop screen.

I then connected the HDMI, which became #2 monitor and selected 'Extend to this display'

I then connected the mini-port to HDMI, which became #3 monitor and selected 'Extend to this display'

My desktop now shows on all three monitors with my VGA connection being the main display.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to change NVIDIA Control Panel .

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I searched for this problem, and although wasn't spot on for me it did give me a clue.

In my case I set the 2nd and the 3rd screen (which wasn't working) to duplicate, which worked. After that I changed things back to extending across all three screens and it worked fine. The three screens looked as they should in the screen resolution window, and user reported all ok.

I was actually fixing it remotely at the time (having returned to my office to ponder the problem), so I rebooted to make sure :)

Answer (score -2):

I have the same issue on my system; two monitors connected to Vga and a third connected to DVI. Most times at startup I only get two monitors coming alive. By right clicking on the desktop and selecting 'Screen Resolution' and then clicking on 'Detect' I usually get the third monitor to come alive (may have to click on detect two or three times!). 
Its not the answer you're looking for but a bit of an answer none the less.